# new instance of backbone view passing an object as argument

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to instantiate and render a view but SOMETIMES I need to pass an extra object to that view called keys.

```
this.$container.append(new app.MyExtraView({'model':model,'keys':keys}).render().el));
```

I'm expecting `this.keys` to be available from within `app.MyExtraView` but it isn't. How can I pass `keys = {}` to `app.MyExtraView` and access it inside `app.MyExtraView` like `this.keys`?

Interestingly the model object behaves in this manner 'automatically'.

Note that this keys object won't be needed every time.

thank you already

Comment: The way you are passing extra object to view looks ok.., try accessing this.options.keys in app.MyExtraView

Comment: There is no `this.options` available, the view object is:
Object->(
$el: Object[1],
cid: "view9",
el: tr,
model: Object,
__proto__: Object
)

Comment: I was passing extra parameter to my View as                             `$(this.el).append(new UserPermissionListView({model:this.model, litype:this.litype}).render().el);`                                 and able to access those parameters in initialize method of View as  `initialize: function (params) {this.litype = params.litype;}`

Comment: as @Uttam suggested, keys should be available via this.options.keys, if it is not the case, please update the question that this.options.keys is not available and show where...